# Reading and writing a csv file Python

Tags: python

I just started learning Python, and I am trying to do the following:
- Read a .csv file
- Write the filtered data in a new file where the column 7 is not blank/empty

When I am printing my results, it shows the right output in the python shelf, but when I am checking my data in the .csv is no correct (differs from what is showing with the print function)
Any suggestion with my code?

Thank you in advance.

```py
file = open("station.csv", "r")
writeFile = open("stations-filtered.csv", "w")

for line in file:
    line2 = line.split(",")
    if line2[7] != "":
        print(line)
        writeFile.write(line)
```

Comment: It's best practice to use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) rather than re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @user513093 that you can use `csv`, like:

```
file = open("station.csv", "r")
writeFile = open("stations-filtered.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(writeFile, delimiter=',')

for line in file:
    line2 = line.split(",")
    if line2[7] != "":
        print(line)
        writer.writerow(line)
```

But still, `pandas` is good:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv("station.csv", sep=",", header=None)
file = file[file[7] != ""]
file.to_csv("stations-filtered.csv")
```